# postinstall script not running after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Title kind of says it all.  This is the scripts portion of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "stencil build --docs",
  "build:prod": "stencil build --prod --config=stencil.config.prod.ts",
  "build:prod:sm": "stencil build --omit=dev --sourceMap=false",
  "build:dev": "stencil build --dev",
  "start": "stencil build --dev --watch --serve",
  "test": "stencil test --spec --e2e",
  "test.watch": "stencil test --spec --e2e --watchAll",
  "generate": "stencil generate",
  "postinstall": "node.exe ./node_modules/path/to/my/package/postinstall.js"
},
```

postinstall.js is in the "files":[] array as well.  My script copies some images from ./node_modules/path/to/my/package/dist/assets/images into ./src/assets/images, creating the folder structure if it isn't there and reports success or failure to the user.

I'm on node.exe v18.17.0 and npm v9.1.2.  I'm installing with `npm install my-package --verbose --foreground-scripts` and I'm not seeing any of the console.log messages that the user should see.  And when I view the log file there are no errors and no indication that the script tried to run.  And most importantly, the directories aren't created and the files aren't copied.

But if I run `node.exe ./node_modules/path/to/my/package/postinstall.js` from the same directory I where I ran npm install, I get the message, the directories are created, and the files are copied.

And I am running npm install, not npm i, to install the package.  I would expect an error that it can't find the postinstall.js file or that there's an error in the script or something if npm tried to run the script.  But nothing.  I thought maybe node wasn't in the path when npm ran, but that should come back with a message that it can't find node.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a test, I added:
,
    "install" : "echo 'installing!",
    "preinstall" : "echo 'preinstalling'",
    "uninstall" : "echo 'uninstalling'"

to package.json and they didn't run either.